# How to center a glyphicon inside a circle using bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I need to center a glyphicon inside an img-circle div using bootstrap 3. I wrote the following html code :

```
<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="img-circle center-block">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker glyphicon-aligned-center"></span>
                </div>
                <p class="aligned-paragraph-address text-center">#123 45678 901 <br/> St NW Pellentesque habitant</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

In css i write the following code:

```
.img-circle {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #f5c63b;
}

.aligned-paragraph-address {
    padding: 1em;
}

.glyphicon-envelope, .glyphicon-phone, .glyphicon-map-marker {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.glyphicon-aligned-center {
    top: 35px;
    left: 35px;
}
```

It's working but I do not feel it's the best practice to do that. So I need a help to do it as a professional.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when I need to center things i use margin: 0 auto;

You can also write it as margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;

But the first solution is less code. If it is text you can try text-align: center;

Good luck. Let me know if this worked for you.